# In ag-grid, how do I show custom options in column set filter?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

My data islike this :

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData([
    {
      name: 'First'
    },
    {
      name: 'Second',
      isDeleted: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Third',
      isDeleted: false,
    }
  ])
});
```

I want to show the Filter options, Deleted and Not Deleted.

I want the option "First" to grouped under "Not deleted" since the filed isDeleted doesn't exist.

https://plnkr.co/edit/o3sN3GodqQumVe09?preview

In this code, if I remove the "isDeleted" value, I see 3 options in the filter: "No", "No", "Yes".

I want to show 2 options only.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in FilterValueGetters (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-getters/#filter-value-getters).  If the value of the field is null then you have to set it manually

I've adjusted your plunker to demonstrate
https://plnkr.co/edit/yHaamucNQoNVzY0F

```
const columnDefs = [
  { field: 'name' },
  { field: 'isDeleted',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      valueFormatter: boolToHuman,
      filterValueGetter: (params) => {
        let value = params.data[params.colDef.field];
        if (value === null || value === undefined){
          value = false;
        }
        return myBoolToHuman(value)
       }
   }
];

function myBoolToHuman(params) {
  return (params === true || params === 'true') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Hope that helps